# Get WooCommerce Orders with meta value in products with a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

I'm making a plugin to get Menus (is a composite product with dishes inside) sold that have a meta value. I'd like to get all products sold with the meta key wcmenu_day and a value. I have as well a Product type that is composite. I made a SQL but is not correct. Something is not working...

```
SELECT DISTINCT pm.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items as woi ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr ON woim.meta_value = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE 'wcmenu_day'
AND pm.meta_value LIKE '2018-08-22'
AND woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
AND tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_type'
AND t.slug LIKE 'composite'
ORDER BY pm.meta_value DESC
```

Could you help?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: The table data comes from WooCommerce and WordPress...

Comment: I don't know how to share the table...